# Not able to get Text using getText(), xpath is not working

Tags: html, selenium, printing, gettext

[image]

```
String printMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@style='font-size:11.5pt']")).getText();
        System.out.println(printMessage);
```

console error is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@style='font-size:11.5pt']"}

Answer (score 2):

as per the screen shot that you shared it seems that the element is within an iframe, You should switch to the iframe to interact with the element.[image]
refer to the below link for more details
[How to handle iframes](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I got the point & now it is working